# Can ERC721A be implemented with opensea proxy

Tags: nft, polygon, opensea

Can ERC721A be implemented with opensea proxy. Please can someone show me an example for eth or polygon? I would like to add gasless transfers. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "opensea proxy"?

Comment: HI @Ismael, I mean this: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol

Comment: From a contract point of view it is doable, just replace OpenZeppelin implementation with an ERC721A compatible implementation.  I don't know if Opensea supports the resulting token.